# Laravel: Variables in localization strings

Tags: laravel, localization, laravel-5.5, laravel-blade

I want to localize my app, but I got a problem:

If I call the trans function like this: `{{ __('permission.addUser') }}`, the output is

> Add new user

If I call `{{$permissions[13]}}` the output is

> addUser

But if I mix them: `{{ __('permission.$permission[13]') }}`, the output is

> permission.$permissions[13]

What's missing? What I did wrong?

Comment: After that, read [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php.)

Comment: @ceeyajoz The parameter in that case is very far from my question. And laravel-blade don't allow double quotes

Comment: Laravel Blade most certainly **does** permit double-quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, I wanted to use my variable as a string.

The solution is `{{ __('permission.' . $permissions[13]) }}`

Answer (score 1):

I know you already have your answer, but in PHP, you can use double quotes to insert variables into strings, for example

```
echo "permission.$permissions_13"
```

will output correctly.
If you want to use arrays or objects, you should wrap them in {}.

```
__("permission.{$permissions[13]}")
```

Remember, double quotes

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In "flat php" I use the double quotes in a lot of situations, but laravel-blade somewhy can't "eat" them. It drop's this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: Oh, I had no idea. Weird. Then yes, your solution sounds correct, string concat :)